# How to specialize enable_if member function of template class in cpp and avoid gcc optimized it out?

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, linker

main.cpp

```
#include "OperatorSave.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  OperatorSave<long> x;
  x.makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(100);
  return 0;
}
```

OperatorSave.cpp

```
#include "OperatorSave.hpp"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
typename std::enable_if<is_one_of<U, long, double>::value>::type
OperatorSave<T>::makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(int a) {
  cout << a << endl;
}

template class OperatorSave<long>;
```

OperatorSave.hpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
template <typename T, typename... P0toN>
struct is_one_of : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename... P1toN>
struct is_one_of<T, T, P1toN...> : public std::true_type {};
template <typename T, typename U, typename... P1toN>
struct is_one_of<T, U, P1toN...> : public is_one_of<T, P1toN...> {};

template <typename T>
struct OperatorSave {
  void makeImgPoolBySmf(int a) { makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(a); }

  template <typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<is_one_of<U, long, double>::value>::type
  makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(int a);
  template <typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<!is_one_of<U, long, double>::value>::type
  makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(int a) {}
};
```

Above files are minimal implementation, in real scene makeImgPoolBySmf_imp could be extremely long, so I have to place definition of template function in cpp and compile it independently with cpp and specialized the class and member function in place for outer usage.

Compile is successful but link failed:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/tmp/main.cpp
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/OperatorSave.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/OperatorSave.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/OperatorSave.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/OperatorSave.cpp.o -c /home/tmp/OperatorSave.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -rdynamic CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/OperatorSave.cpp.o -o main
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x23): undefined reference to `std::enable_if<is_one_of<long, long, double>::value, void>::type OperatorSave<long>::makeImgPoolBySmf_imp<long>(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:113: main] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tmp'
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

My question is :

1. does my specialization: template class OperatorSave<long>; bring the function makeImgPoolBySmf_imp specialized togethor?
2. how could I make makeImgPoolBySmf_imp specialized and compiled link successfully.
3. Since my project is huge, I have other member function implemented way similar like makeImgPoolBySmf_imp , which is actually specialized and  compiled but optimized like:

   ```
   0000000000009fc0 t _ZN12OperatorSaveI5DPUv2E20makeImgPoolBySmf_impIS0_EENSt9enable_ifIXsr9is_one_ofIT_JS0_6DPUv3e7DPUv3me6DPUv4e6DPUv4f5XVDPU6XV2DPUEE5valueEvE4typeESt10shared_ptrI8SwimPoolEjjjjjj.isra.0
   0000000000000804 t _ZN12OperatorSaveI5DPUv2E20makeImgPoolBySmf_impIS0_EENSt9enable_ifIXsr9is_one_ofIT_JS0_6DPUv3e7DPUv3me6DPUv4e6DPUv4f5XVDPU6XV2DPUEE5valueEvE4typeESt10shared_ptrI8SwimPoolEjjjjjj.isra.0.cold
   ```

   That cannot link, how to fix that?
   Since compiler optimization conditions are of great amount, I cannot reproduce the 'isra' case yet.

I have try compiled them together like:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp OperatorSave.cpp OperatorSave.hpp
```

It's successful, but I cannot compile them at one time in production environment, because some of the cpp are really huge, I have to compile them in parallel and link them together.

Besides, symbol name map of  OperatorSave.cpp.o is

```
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_OperatorSave.cpp
0000000000000000 W _ZN12OperatorSaveIlE16makeImgPoolBySmfEi
                 U _ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
0000000000000000 W _ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc
                 U _ZNSo3putEc
                 U _ZNSo5flushEv
                 U _ZNSolsEi
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt16__throw_bad_castv
                 U _ZSt4cout
0000000000000000 b _ZStL8__ioinit
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
```

It seems only non-enable_if declared function is successfully specialized.

Comment: Never use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Include individual headers instead.

Comment: Also please check the reference on how to use `enable_if`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: @kiner_shah thank you for the link, I have read it twice and I believe the problem is the specialization of function separated declared with enable_if and sadly there's few of exist docs mention it. Would you please just fix my case in code?

Comment: Are you sure you implemented:
OperatorSave<long>::makeImgPoolBySmf_imp<long>(int) ?

Cause i dont think it is about enable_if, but the compiler cannot find the implementation of makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(int a);

Comment: @HeinBreukers Yes, I place it in OperatorSave.cpp, and add a specialization of class OperatorSave<long>; telling compiler to create a type OperatorSave<long> with all member method compiled and generate symbol (which I hope so). As you say, I am also wondering does my specialization works.

Comment: @BenedictWilliam Ah yes i see right now in OperatorSave.cpp. Did you also implement template class OperatorSave<long>; or have you only declared it like shown?

Comment: @HeinBreukers if you mean the instance object of type "class OperatorSave", I did in main.cpp, but while compiler dealing with OperatorSave.cpp, it cannot see the instance object.

Comment: @BenedictWilliam I mean specifically the definition of the template specialized class, OperatorSave<long>. If you declared it but dont implement OperatorSave<long>::makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(int a), then the method does not exist.

Comment: @HeinBreukers My previous description is wrong. "template class OperatorSave<long>;" is not “specialization" but "instantiation", and my purpose is to instantiate the function makeImgPoolBySmf_imp.

Comment: @BenedictWilliam Ah i see, i didnt know about explicit template instatiation.

Comment: @HeinBreukers I already find the solution: after definition of template function, add an explicit instantiation: template std::enable_if<is_one_of<long, long, double>::value>::type OperatorSave<long>::makeImgPoolBySmf_imp(int a); since enable_if is also a template, we have to instantiate 2 templates at one time, or gcc report error. However thanks a lot, discussion with you brings me so many ideas and I 
 finally made it solved~ thinking is tough, but result is delightful.

Comment: @BenedictWilliam Great that you found the solution!